# Understanding info gc-roots in Cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to debug a GC problem in Lion. My subclasses of NSDocument, NSWindowController, and NSWindow get collected properly in 10.6 but not 10.7.

I have examined the output of "info gc-roots" but I don't understand exactly what it is telling me. I found no documentation on interpreting the output. If I have overlooked it, I hope someone will point me to it.

Here is the output for the window:

```
(gdb) info gc-roots 0x181b3f0
Number of roots: 1
Root:
   0 Kind: bytes   rc:   1  Address: 0x019666c0  Offset: 0x00000014
   1 Kind: object  rc:   0  Address: 0x0181b3f0  Class: CCMDocumentWindow

(gdb) po 0x019666c0
<__NSAutoBlock__: 0x19666c0>
```

The window controller:

```
(gdb) info gc-roots 0x14f3680
Number of roots: 1
Root:
   0 Kind: bytes   rc:   1  Address: 0x019666c0  Offset: 0x00000014
   1 Kind: object  rc:   0  Address: 0x0181b3f0  Class: CCMDocumentWindow  ivar: NSWindow.NSResponder
   2 Kind: object  rc:   0  Address: 0x014f3680  Class: CCMWindowCtl
```

and the document:

```
(gdb) info gc-roots 0x181e690
Number of roots: 0
```

My questions are:

1. The output for the document puzzles me particularly. If there are no roots, shouldn't it get collected?
2. Is there any useful information in the lines labeled 0?
3. Where do I go from here in figuring out why GC is failing on 10.7? (I filed a support incident with Apple, but they rejected it and told me to file a bug instead.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It won't get collected if the retain count is >0.  GC is a hybrid system on OS X;  CFRetain()/CFRelease() still does hard retain/releases that effectively tell the collector to not collect something.  So, this is a leak in the traditional retain/release context.
2. Yes -- that tells you that there is an allocation at 0x019666c0 that is an untyped structure (i.e. the debugger doesn't know what it is) and the reference to the next item in the root chain is at offset 0x00000014.  This root is retained;  RC: 1.
3. File a bug and attach your binary.   You can further debug this by turning on malloc logging and doing `info malloc 0x019666c0` in the debugger.  That'll give you the allocation history at that address and should indicate who allocated that structure that isn't freeing it (or is failing to call CFRelease()).   Or you can do the same on any item in the chain of roots.

(Yes, this was all in the context of `window`.)

Comment: Thank you, Bill! rdar# 9767246. AFAICT the extra retain is happening in Apple code.